# ArrayList Generic Sorter

Tags: java

I want to pass in an arraylist and sort it no matter whats in it
Error I am getting: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Character

```
  ArrayList myArray = new ArrayList();
        myArray.add("wayne");
        myArray.add("bob");
        myArray.add('h');
        myArray.add(4);
        myArray.add(5.50);
       ArrayList sortedArray =   Validate.Sort(myArray);

       for(Object x:  sortedArray)
       {
           System.out.println(x);
       }
```

---

```
 public static ArrayList Sort(ArrayList value)
      {


          Collections.sort(value);

          return value;
      }
```

Comment: There is no such default sort, you would have to define your own.

Comment: Just a note, you can just do `Collections.sort(value)`, returning the `List` is pointless because `Collections.sort(value)` will rearrange the elements in your `Collection` already.

Answer (score 3):

Your `ArrayList` has a mix of `String` and `char` values. So when the two try to get compared, the `String`'s `compareTo` method is being called. It has a signature of `compareTo(String,String)`, so it's trying to cast the `char` to a `String`. Either put all `String`s in, or write a custom comparator that handles mixed types like this.

Comment: And use the generic on your `List` types; their whole purpose is to prevent this type of error.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Comparator:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

In your case the `compareTo()` may look like:

```
public int compareTo(Object a, Object b){
    if(a == b)
       return 0;
    if(a==null)
       return 1;
    if(b==null)
        return -1;
    return a.toString().compareTo(b.toString);
}
```

But I think this would be kind of useless.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to pass in an arraylist and sort it no matter whats in it

What is this supposed to mean? A total ordering is a binary relation which satisfies some properties (antisimmetry, transitivity, totality). More easily, given two elements, you must identify a criterion to determine which is smaller/bigger than the other.

You cannot do this, unless you know what these elements actually are. If you want to sort an array of whatever, given object A and B, whose types you don't even know, how can you tell which is bigger than the other?

In Java, you might use the hashCode, which is indeed a criterion, but it's hardly useful. If you want to avoid duplicates, you can use a `Set` rather than a `List`. Anyway, if you really want to sort elements based on their hashCode, you can do it like this:

```
private static final Comparator<Object> hashComparator
        = new Comparator<Object>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Object a, Object b) {
        return System.identityHashCode(a) - System.identityHashCode(b);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        //this is a static singleton, nothing can be equal to it
        return false;
    }
};

public static ArrayList Sort(ArrayList value)
{
    Collections.sort(value, hashComparator);
    return value;
}
```

---

**EDIT**: if you are interested in sorting a list of just Strings and Characters (or if you want to sort items based on their string representation) the right thing to do is probably convert everything to strings, or use a `SortedMap<String, Object>`. Otherwise, you can do the same I just showed you before, but using a more specific `compare` function, such as:

```
public int compare(Object a, Object b) {
    return a.toString().compareTo(b.toString());
}
```